# How to unload a javascript from an html?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I unload a JavaScript resource with all its defined objects from the DOM?

Im developing a simple framework that enables to load html fragments into a "main" html. Each fragment is self contained and may include references to additional JS and CSS files. The JS and CSS resources are parsed and dynamically added to the html. When the fragment is removed/replaced from the DOM I want to remove its JS and CSS.

If I remove the script element in the example below, the functions defined in page1.js are still available.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="page1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
<body>
...
```

Is there a way to unload page1.js objects from the DOM?

========= The test code I use =======

I tried the advice i got in the comments below; to delete the added objects using a cleanup function - but even this fails. The sources i used for testing:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadJSFile(){
        var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        scriptTag.setAttribute("src", "simple.js");

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        head.appendChild(scriptTag);
    }

    function unloadJSFile(){            
        delete window.foo;
        delete window.cleanup;
        alert("cleanedup. typeof window.foo is " + (typeof window.foo));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

  Hello JavaScript Delete

  <br/>
  <button onclick="loadJSFile();">Click to load JS</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="foo();">call foo()</button>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="unloadJSFile();">Click to unload JS</button>

</body>
</html>
```

simple.js source:

```
var foo = function(){
    alert("hello from foo");
}
```

Comment: If you look at it in an objective manner, you are trying to do the same as in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830133/avoiding-pollution-of-globals-via-iframe-script-loader/3882324#3882324. . iframes seem to be a fairly normal way to do as much as is possible regarding cleanup.

Comment: @Ravindra: I cant use iFrames because i do not know what is the dimension of the fragment, in addition, the fragment needs to communicate with the existing code on the page.

Comment: Are the resource JS maintained by you? If yes, a bit of architecture around the JS will be surely of help. The answers below by cdhowie and elusive would be of help

Comment: No, the resources are not maintained by me. Its a framework for others to use. thats my main problem, i want to make it as simple as possible for 3rd party developers to use it without the need to follow specific design patterns.

Comment: If you really want this done put a script at the top of your page `<script src=load_save.js></script>` which ends document load and then requests the same page using AJAX or whatever and modifies the scripts so they are pre-src=url.  Load page document with modified pre-src values modify the scripts then see what changes.

Comment: where can you put a script on the page beginning, end, middle only?  This greatly alters our technique.

Comment: @totach It would be good to mark as accepted one answer from below.

Comment: @Totach: Did you get to a good solution? I'm facing the same question. Thanks!

Comment: For some of you it could be feasible to just reload the page to "unload" all the javascript which came from a specific script. For my scenario it was an easy solution to get rid of all the dynamic loaded javaScript.

Answer (score 18):

This cannot be done.

When a script is executed, function definitions are added to the global `window` object.  There may be debugging symbols attached to the function that indicate where the function came from, but this information is not available to scripts.

About the only way you could achieve something like this would be to create a pseudo-namespace in the script and then throw away that whole namespace when you are done with it.  However, this question hints to me that you are trying to do something the wrong way.  Perhaps elaborating on your scenario would help us provide alternate solutions.

Comment: Thanks - adding the objects to a namespace and then deleting it seems like the best approach.

Comment: @Totach: The memory-leaks are still an issue when using this approach, but you probably took care of that, already.

Answer (score 7):

No, that is not possible. You could build a simple cleanup function that removes all variables that were defined in that file:

```
var foo = 'bar';
var cleanup = function () {
    delete window.foo;
    delete window.cleanup;
};

// unload all resources
cleanup();
```

Another approach would be to use a modular object structure for your fragments, that clean up after themselves. That involves a slightly higher overhead but is probably worth it, as it makes the code much easier to read and maintain:

```
// creates the object using the second parameter as prototype.
// .create() is used as constructor
GlobalModuleHandlerThingy.addModule('my_module', {
    create: function () {
        this.foo = 'bar';
        return this;
    },
    foo: null,
    destroy: function () {
        // unload events, etc.
    }
});

GlobalModuleHandlerThingy.getModule('my_module').foo; // => bar
GlobalModuleHandlerThingy.unloadModule('my_module'); // calls .destroy() on the module and removes it.
```

Comment: Possible but requires to define the cleanup manually and may result in memory leaks. I need this solution for a simple framework im writing which enables a single html to dynamically load html fragments that link to additional JS & CSS resources. When fragments are replaced, i need to unload their JS and CSS context.

Comment: @Totach: Right, but this is the only way of ridding yourself of those variables. Detaching events, etc needs to be considered when doing it like this. This is just a simple example.

Comment: I tried your solution but for some strange reason - the objects cant be deleted!? (false is returned in firefox). Note that the script is loaded dynamically by creating a script tag. Any idea? many thanks!

Comment: @Totach: I tried the following using firebugs console: `var foo = 'bar', cleanup = function () { delete window.foo; delete window.cleanup; }; cleanup();` and it works like expected. What is your exact error message?

Comment: In the console it works for me too. But in the html I load the script by creating a script tag and attach it to the head element (using JavaScript). When I try to delete objects that were added by the attached script, "false" is returned and the objects remain defined. What I do notice is that if I use a namespace object, the namespace object cant be deleted but objects defined on the namespace can be deleted... (thanks again)

Comment: @Totach: That is strange. It works for me (i built a small test case locally). And i am able to `delete` objects on any page using firebugs console or the script.

Comment: Please check the simple example I added to my question (the initial question). When I run it in FF - the delete doesn't work.

Comment: @Totach: You cannot `delete foo;`, since `delete` needs an object to operate on. Prefix it with `window.` to achieve the desired effect (this is needed since it is defined in the global scope).

Comment: The code tries to delete foo and window.foo ... both dont work (i removed the delete foo line).

Answer (score 6):

perhaps you need to consider conditionally loading it rather than conditionally unloading it...

Answer (score 3):

you can make them = null

```
    function fnc1 (){

    }

    window.fnc1  = null
    //or
    window["fnc1"]  = null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to unload a specific object, it's fairly easy: just set it to `{}`

ie:  `myobj = {};`

So if you know what objects are created in a particular include, it won't be hard at all.

On the other hand, if you don't know what objects are created in a particular include, there isn't a mechansim to find out - you can't ask Javascript to tell you what was defined in a particular include.

However, I would say that if you don't know what objects are being loaded in a particular javascript file, you're probably not doing yourself any favours in loading it (you should always have a reasonable idea what code does in your site), or in trying to unload it manually (if you don't know what it does, that implies its a third party include, which means that unsetting it manually is likely to break things).

Comment: it could be done too with functions: `function name()={}`

Answer (score 0):

Was researching for something like that myself and thought I'll post my findings

1. Wrap your stuff in a global namespace in js file so it can be removed easily, ie 
   var stuff = { blabla: 1, method: function(){} };
2. When you need to get rid of it, simply set stuff = {}, or null even
3. Remove script tag from page

*** If you use requirejs - [require js remove definition to force reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899967/require-js-remove-definition-to-force-reload/18521604#18521604)

Note: as long as you don't reference modules inside the namespace from anywhere else everything will be collected by GC and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured a trick for this. I was wondering here days finding an answer for this and I just realized a perfect trick to do this without trying to unload the java Script. only you have to do is create a global variable like `currentPage` in your `main` page's java script and when you loading the page assign the page name to `currentPage` . then in every other `.js` file use `$('document').ajaxComplete()` insted of `$('document').ready()` add an if statement as first line inside every `$('document').ajaxComplete()` function. set it to check `currentPage` variable equals to a new page name. add all other events inside if statement. i don't know English very well so check my code. and This is my first answer here so sorry if i make some mistakes.

main.html

```
<body>
    <div id='container></div>
    <button id="load1">
    <button id="load1">
</body>
```

main.js

```
var currentPage = "";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load1').click(function () {
        loadSource('page1', 'body');
    });
    $('#load2').click(function () {
        loadSource('page2', 'body');
    });
});

function loadSource( page, element){
    currentPage = page;
    $('#container').load('views/' + page + '.php', element);
    $.getScript('js/' + page + '.js');
    $('#css').prop('disabled', true).remove();
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/' + page + '.css" type="text/css" />');
}
```

> all of my pages scripts and styles are in seperate folders views, js, css.

page1.html

```
<body>
    <button id="test1">
    <button id="test2">
</body>
```

page1.js

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    if(currentPage == 'page1'){
        /*$('#test1').click(function () {
            console.log('page1');
        });*/
        $('#test2').click(function () {
            console.log('page1');
        });
    }
});
```

page2.html

```
<body>
    <button id="test1">
    <button id="test2">
</body>
```

page2.js

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    if(currentPage == 'page2'){
        $('#test1').click(function () {
            console.log('page2');
        });
        /*$('#test2').click(function () {
            console.log('page2');
        });*/
    }
});
```

> i commented one button in each script to check if that button still has old script's affect.