# Access original globals and attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, global-variables

I'm working on code that is injected on web pages (using a browser add-on or with a script tag).

The problem is that we want to use global objects and variables like `JSON`, `window.location`, `String.split`, etc. and the implementation of these may have been changed by the web page. This may make our code fail, and it is a security problem.

Example:

```
>>> String.prototype.split = function() { return 'foo'; };
function()
>>> 'a,b,c'.split(',');  // gives unexpected result
"foo"
```

So, is there a way to get access to the browser's default implementation of objects and functions as they were before they were changed? It does not have to be standard, I just want the functionality to exist.

Comment: It depends on the browser. For example, context scripts in Chrome are executed in their own sandbox, so there should be no problem regarding this. Similarly, since Firefox addons are executed in a different environment (the browser, not the page) you'll always have access to the original methods (of course that won't help with page specific properties such as `window.location` (which is readonly anyway afaik)). Don't know about other browsers. In any other case, using an `iframe` seems to be the only option.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with code that has to run on any page (and that we're not always using an add-on). You're right that window seems to be read only. Assignment to window is just ignored (tested in FF). The iframe solution seems to be the way to go, also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830133/avoiding-pollution-of-globals-via-iframe-script-loader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Perhaps a more viable way would be to create an empty `<iframe>` dynamically.

Here's an example that contaminates `String.prototype.split` in the parent window but gets a clean one from `<iframe>`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onBodyLoad() {

        String.prototype.split = function() { return 'foo'; }; // contaminate original window
        console.log(String.prototype.split); // yeah, it's contaminated

        var acr = document.getElementById("accessor");
        acr.onclick = function ()
        {
            var dummyFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
            document.body.appendChild(dummyFrame); 
            console.log(dummyFrame.contentWindow.String.prototype.split); // uncontaminated
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <a href="#" id="accessor">Access iframe Window object</a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

<strike>Not in the ordinary sense; although there might be some exotic hacks out there.</strike>

The only way I could think of, was to make sure your code gets loaded before any other script. If that requirement if fulfilled, necessary global variables can be cloned into a safe location.

Comment: +1 I was just in the process of writing about the `iframe` solution.

Comment: With the `iframe` having the same origin as the parent document, the parent can still write to the child document's `String.prototype` to corrupt it. The `iframe` solution is only a safe sandbox when going cross-domain.

Comment: @bobince - Sure, but how can a parent write into a child document when other (possibly interfering) scripts have already or not yet been executed? A dynamically created `iframe` doesn't exist for previous scripts and it's BOM/DOM can be shielded from later scripts by cloning relevant functionality into a safehouse variable in the unlikely case when that dynamically created `iframe` DOM element is somehow picked up and messed around with.

Comment: @Saul Yes, I think the solution is to create the iframe and store the references you need somewhere safe (in an object that only your own code has access to), because the iframe can't be trusted once the code that created it returns (because it seems like it has to be added to the DOM).